# Connecting thermal printer on clients side via webusbapi and zadig

Tags: angular, printing, thermal-printer, webusb, bixolon-printer

I'm trying to connect thermal printer on clients side through web app. (Frontend angular, backend c#)

First I got Access denied, and then after Zadig I managed to open connection to thermal printer, and print some stuff (so that works).
[image]

Since Zadig replaces driver of that selected printer, the other problem I'm facing is that the printer is not working anymore in 'normal' mode...like when I try to print some receipt from pdf or try to print the test page through printer properties...it just does nothing now (and vice versa, when I remove Zadig driver, and put default one, printer works in normal mode, but can't connect to web app)

Also here is a screenshot of driver details of that printer (for some reason that printer is now greyed out in control panel -> devices and printers)

[image]

Does anybody have some kind of a solution for this?

Comment: I tried just now with adding additional printer, and yes I can have different settings, but I can-t have different drivers, because both printers use the same port.
I was using this tutorial for adding additional printer https://www.howtogeek.com/362957/how-to-install-the-same-printer-twice-with-different-settings-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good solution to this problem. From the perspective of Windows you have two drivers for the same device and you can't have them both running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, do you have some kind of other solution. I'm just really surprised that I can't put some kind of persmissions on the printer for web app to use it...it doesn't make any sense